# The tabs dont fill the tablayout

Tags: java, android

The tabs don't fill the tab layout like [this](http://i61.tinypic.com/r9igd5.png)

How can i make them to full the tab layout when every `tab == max width/2`

**main activity java:**

```
ViewPager mviewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mviewPager.setAdapter(new viewpager(getSupportFragmentManager(),MainActivity.this));

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mviewPager);
```

**main activity xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/Colorprimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:id="@+id/my_tool_bar"
   />

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabMode="scrollable"
    />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
```

**fragment pager apdater java:**

```
    package com.example.smite.floater;


import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.widget.Switch;

public class viewpager extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    final int fragments_counter=2;
    private String titles[] = new String[]{"main","creator"};
    private Context context;

    public viewpager(FragmentManager fm , Context context){
        super(fm);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments_counter;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position){

            case 0:
                return new main();
            case 1:
                default:
                return new creator();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        // Generate title based on item position
        return titles[position];
    }

}
```

my app theme parent is `parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"`

thank's for helping (:

Comment: You can use PagerSlidingTabStrip

Comment: Don't use `PagerSlidingTabStrip` if Google has their own support library for this. When in doubt, consult: https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare.

Comment: what happens if you remove `app:tabMode="scrollable"`

Comment: @guy1820       did you get an answer to your problem? did the answer below help you?

Answer (score 4):

If you put the line `"app:tabMode="scrollable"`, then the tablayout width will not fill the entire screen. The best solution is this.
Put this line in XML

```
    app:tabMode="fixed"
```

and in Java, do

```
    if(tabLayout.getTabCount() > MAX_NUMBER) {
       tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);
    }
```

MAX_NUMBER is some number depending on your requirement. I have used 3, you may use 3,4 or whatever suits your requirement.
This will ensure that if there are only a few tabs, they will occupy the entire width, and be scrollable if not.

Comment: If this answer helped you, please mark it as accepted. If it didn't, let me know more about the issue.

Comment: Your answer has helped me solve the same problem of tabs  not filling the tab layout. so this means if i put `app:tabMode="scrollable` and the width is bigger, tabs won't expand to fill the entire width. but if i put  `app:tabMode="fixed"` they will. i thought they will expand in both cases.       thanks man for your answer